# Artemis : Count message using CLI

Tags: activemq-artemis

Which command is used to count total number of messages in ActiveMQ Artemis using command line? When I am executing following command, it will gives details about queue

```
artemis.cmd queue stat --user admin --password admin --queueName ExpiryQueue --url tcp://localhost:61617
```

Is there any way to get the total number of messages only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Artemis CLI command which will provide the *total* number of messages on the broker. However, you can use the management API from the command-line using `curl`, e.g.:

```
curl -k --user admin:admin -H "Origin: http://localhost:8161" "http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/TotalMessageCount"
```

The URL will obviously change based on your broker's configuration. The port specified on the URL is the port where the embedded web server is listening (configured in `bootstrap.xml`).

The response will be JSON formatted, but you can use other command-line tools to parse the JSON, e.g.:

```
curl -s -k --user admin:admin -H "Origin: http://localhost:8161" "http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/TotalMessageCount" | jq -r
```

Comment: To run this commands on the Windows PowerShell and echo the total number of messages: `$response = Invoke-RestMethod -headers @{'Origin' = 'http://localhost:8161'; 'Authorization' = 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' } -uri "http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/TotalMessageCount"; echo $response.value`